# Fragment on LinearLayout for button and textview component

Tags: android, android-fragments

My current code layout no fragment at the moment, 
I need to make a little change on Status(-/Picking/Picked) and Button(Pick-enable/disable) to  **fragment** because I need to keep the data for status and button(enable/disable) always up-to-date/sync to database.

The apps and same piece of data would use by few authorize users. If one of user click on "Pick" button,the rest of user who use the apps,particular Pick button should be disable and status should display "Picking" immediately  without refresh the whole layout.

I'm quite new on android apps development, although have some idea/logic to do it but a bit confuse...

Following is my current code...
Hope someone advice me where is the proper place to plant in the "**fragment**",so I could run a **thread** behind to get rest service info then display up-to-date value on status and Pick button accordingly immediately without refresh the whole layout .

```
<LinearLayout 
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/code"
        .../>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/name"
        .../>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/qty"
        .../>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/status"
        .../>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/pickButton"
        ...
        android:text="@string/pick" />
/>
```

.

On the Activity

```
public class blablaActivity extends ListActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();        
        new HttpRequestTask().execute();
    }

    private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<PickerItemDetail>> {
    //private SkuArrayAdapter m_adapter; 
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<PickerItemDetail> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/picking";
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            List<PickerItemDetail> resultList = Arrays.asList(restTemplate.getForObject(url, PickerItemDetail[].class));
            ArrayList<PickerItemDetail> pickerList = new ArrayList<PickerItemDetail>();
            if(resultList.size()>0){
                for(int i=0;i<resultList.size();i++){
                    PickerItemDetail pickerItemDetail = resultList.get(i);                  
                    pickerList.add(pickerItemDetail);

                }
            }

            return pickerList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ListFruitActivity:doInBackground", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<PickerItemDetail> pickerList) {
        try{
            m_adapter = new SkuArrayAdapter(PickerItemActivity.this,pickerList);
            setListAdapter(m_adapter);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("ListFruitActivity:onPostExecute", e.getMessage(), e);

        }

    }

}


}
```

ArrayAdapter...

```
public class SkuArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PickerItemDetail>{

private ArrayList<PickerItemDetail> objects;
private String currentsku;
public SkuArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<PickerItemDetail> objects){
    super(context,R.layout.activity_list_fruit,objects);
    this.objects = objects;

}

public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
    // assign the view we are converting to a local variable
            View v = convertView;

            // first check to see if the view is null. if so, we have to inflate it.
            // to inflate it basically means to render, or show, the view.
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_fruit, null);
            }

            /*
             * Recall that the variable position is sent in as an argument to this method.
             * The variable simply refers to the position of the current object in the list. (The ArrayAdapter
             * iterates through the list we sent it)
             * 
             * Therefore, i refers to the current Item object.
             */
            PickerItemDetail i = objects.get(position);

            if (i != null) {
                               TextView code = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.code);
                TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
                TextView qty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.qty);
                TextView status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.status);
                Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.pickButton);

                                  //some code....//

                            }
                           return v

}
```

Comment: check this  http://androidhive.blogspot.in/2013/05/fragment-activity-in-android-coding.html?m=1   i feel only to keep ur button state upto date you should not use fragments

Comment: Then what alternate solution that I should use?
I need to keep button and Status up-to-date
Thanks advice

Comment: help me understand what is your problem and what are you trying to do ?